# Filter two tables based on dates and sum the result in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a problem summing the result of two tables. The first table has the sold quantities. The second table has the forecasted quantities. Both tables are linked to a calendar table (not represented). The third table has cut-off dates for both products.

Exported:

| Product | Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2022 | 10 |
| A | 2/1/2022 | 10 |
| A | 3/1/2022 | 10 |
| B | 1/1/2022 | 5 |
| B | 2/1/2022 | 5 |
| B | 3/1/2022 | 5 |

Forecast:

| Product | Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2022 | 20 |
| A | 2/1/2022 | 20 |
| A | 3/1/2022 | 20 |
| A | 4/1/2022 | 20 |
| B | 1/1/2022 | 15 |
| B | 2/1/2022 | 15 |
| B | 3/1/2022 | 15 |
| B | 4/1/2022 | 15 |

Cut Off Dates

| Product | CutOffDate |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2/1/2022 |
| B | 3/1/2022 |

The first goal is to filter both tables with the cut off date, getting from the first table and the product A & B:

| Product | Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2022 | 10 |
| A | 2/1/2022 | 10 |
| B | 1/1/2022 | 5 |
| B | 2/1/2022 | 5 |
| B | 3/1/2022 | 5 |

Those dates are <=2/1/2022 for product A (The cut off date for product A) and <=3/1/2022 for product B (The cut off date for product B).

After that I need the same for table 2, but considering the dates after the cut off date:

| Product | Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3/1/2022 | 20 |
| A | 4/1/2022 | 20 |
| B | 4/1/2022 | 15 |

Next, I need to mix both tables to obtain:

| Product | Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2022 | 10 |
| A | 2/1/2022 | 10 |
| A | 3/1/2022 | 20 |
| A | 4/1/2022 | 20 |
| B | 1/1/2022 | 5 |
| B | 2/1/2022 | 5 |
| B | 3/1/2022 | 5 |
| B | 4/1/2022 | 15 |

Finally, my goal is to have the following result:

| Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | 15 |
| 2/1/2022 | 15 |
| 3/1/2022 | 25 |
| 4/1/2022 | 35 |

Thanks in advance!

I tried to do it using max for the dates, but I can't keep the Product context filter, causing that my table is only filtered by my maximum cut off date (3/1/2022)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this **Calculated Table** to get your desired result:

```
Result = 
VAR _tbl = 
    UNION(
        FILTER(
            Exported,
            Exported[Date] <= RELATED('Cut Off Dates'[CutOffDate])
        ), 
        FILTER(
            Forecast,
            Forecast[Date] > RELATED('Cut Off Dates'[CutOffDate])
        )
    )
RETURN
    GROUPBY(
        _tbl,
        [Date],
        "Quantity", SUMX( CURRENTGROUP(), [Quantity])
    )
```

but make sure you have a relation between your 3 input tables on the *Product* columns

[image]